# Has this C code a defined behavior?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior

This is a thought experiment, not production code nor good coding style.

Suppose we have this function

```
int find_process_pid_by_name(char* name, int* threads_in_process);
```

that return the *PID* of a named process and also always store into `threads_in_process` the number of threads running in said process.

A lazy programmer, interested only on the *PID*, writes this code

```
int pid = find_process_pid_by_name("a process name", &pid);
```

Does it trigger undefined behavior?

Comment: I guess if you access `threads_in_process[i], i = 1,2,3..` in your function `find_process_pid_by_name` that will be undefined behaviour!

Comment: It is well defined. As mentioned in the answers, there is a sequence point right before the function returning, which means that any previous side effects have taken place.

Comment: Strictly, you're passing a `const char *` to a function that takes a `char *`; if the function modifies what's passed, you get undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No — I don't think it is undefined behaviour.   There's a sequence point immediately before the function is called (after the arguments and the expression that denotes the called function have been evaluated), and there's another before the called function returns.  Any side-effects on `pid` performed by the called function have been completed before the function finishes returning.  The result of the function is then assigned to `pid`.  There's no question of the location that is assigned to being changed by the function.  I see nothing that invokes undefined behaviour.

I am assuming that the called function treats the `int *` argument as a write-only pointer to a single value.  If it reads from a single value, we need to know that `pid` was previously initialized (formally; in practice, it won't matter). In the context, `pid` has not been initialized; the result of the function will initialize it.  So, if the function reads from its pointer argument, technically, you have undefined behaviour.  If the function treats the pointer as the start of a multi-element array and accesses beyond the zeroth element, there are problems.  But these are issues somewhat outside the intended scope of the question/discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I believe this code is well defined. There's a sequence point at the end of the function, before the return value is copied into the calling context. So the function will first assign to `pid` indirectly through `threads_in_process`, then it will return, and then the return value will be assigned to `pid`.